# React: FitBounds issue when passing array of longlat - react-mapbox-gl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Am trying to use fitBounds to make all my markers visible with a proper zoom level.

```
getBounds(){
   return [[12.49637,41.90278],[12.319398,45.441906],[13.055054,47.809532],[16.373724,48.208244]]
}

<Map
   style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
   containerStyle={{
     height: "100%",
     width: "100%"
   }}
   fitBounds={this.getBounds()}>
     <markers /> 
</Map>
```

and am getting this error

```
Error: Invalid LngLat object: (12.49637,41.90278, 12.319398,45.441906)
 at new LngLat (bundle.js:118874)
 at Function.LngLat.convert (bundle.js:118874)
 at LngLatBounds.setSouthWest (bundle.js:118876)
 at new LngLatBounds (bundle.js:118876)
 at Function.LngLatBounds.convert (bundle.js:118876)
 at e.i.fitBounds (bundle.js:119021)
 at ReactMapboxGl.ReactMapboxFactory.ReactMapboxGl.componentDidMount (bundle.js:124648)
 at commons.js:19945
 at measureLifeCyclePerf (commons.js:19755)
 at commons.js:19944
```

Am not getting whats wrong here. Please help me with this.

Here the react-component am using [alex3165/react-mapbox-gl](https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input am passing to fitBounds should be in the form of `Array<Array<number>>`

```
getMinOrMax(markersObj, minOrMax, latOrLng) {
 if(minOrMax == "max"){
  return _.maxBy(markersObj, function (value) {
      return value[latOrLng]
  })[latOrLng];
 }else{
  return _.minBy(markersObj, function (value) {
      return value[latOrLng]
  })[latOrLng];
 }
}

getBounds(markersObj) {
  var maxLat = this.getMinOrMax(markersObj, "max", "lat");
  var minLat = this.getMinOrMax(markersObj, "min", "lat");
  var maxLng = this.getMinOrMax(markersObj, "max", "lng");
  var minLng = this.getMinOrMax(markersObj, "min", "lng");

  var southWest = [minLng, minLat];
  var northEast = [maxLng, maxLat];
  return [southWest, northEast];
}
```

So am using the above methods to find figure out SouthWest and NorthEast points from the given array of marker position objects.

Marker sample objects should to be like below:

```
var markerPoints = [{lng:12.49637,lat:41.90278},{lng:12.319398,lat:45.441906},{lng:13.055054,lat:47.809532},{lng:16.373724,lat:48.208244}]

<Map
  style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
  containerStyle={{
   height: "100%",
   width: "100%"
  }}
  fitBounds={this.getBounds(markerPoints)}>
  <markers /> 
</Map>
```

Note: Am using lodash liblary for utility functions like min and max in the example.

Thanks,
Josan

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the wrong bounds format to the fitBounds() function.

Fit bounds expects as an argument: `fitBounds : Array<Array<number>>`

See the docs: https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl/blob/master/docs/API.md

In mapbox this is called an "LngLatBoundsLike Object", see here: 
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#lnglatlike

So your function call must be something like this:

`fitBounds([[12.49637,41.90278],[12.319398,45.441906]]);`

Where the first argument is the southwest corner and the second argument is the northeast corner of your desired bounding box

Comment: Thanks @Andi-lo i have seen somewhere saying we can pass array of marker positions to `fitBounds` options if you can't figure out SW and NE points. So i asked that way. and eventually figured out the way to get required points also posted as a detailed answer.